# Interpreting Outputs From a Generalised Linear Mixed Model

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, interpretation, genstat

So I am running an experiment on transmission fidelity in humans depending on information type. This works by having chains of 5 people playing a Chinese whispers type game with 4 passages of information where the information is passed through the chain and information maintained investigated.

There are 4 different information types, passages also come in 4 orders (they can be done 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th). Each chain has 5 positions. The fact that chains aren't independent and neither are participants (they each do 4 passages) means I included these two terms as random factors. As this is proportional data, I used a binomial distribution with a logit function. I used GenStat to perform my analysis (supervisor recommended it).

I ran 2 analyses concerning this question, the first investigating overall information maintenance (proportion of information passed on compared to the original information, generation 0) and the second investigating previous information maintenance (information passed on compared to the previous generation).

I found for the first GLMM, a significant effect of position and order*type.
For the second GLMM, a significant effect of position*type, no effect of order.
Genstat doesn't seem to tell you about fixed effects when there is an interaction, maybe it cannot calculate this, I don't know.

What is confusing me is how to interpret this - My understanding is that a person maintains more information overall if they are positioned in an early generation (makes sense, information can only degrade, not improve) They also maintain more information depending on when it is received (1st 2nd etc) and what type it is. There is a fatigue affect with some types and a learning affect with others.
A person maintains the previous information depending on their position in the chain and what type of information they receive. There is no effect of order on their previous information maintenance.

I guess where I am lost is why you'd get an effect of order in the first test but not in the second, how and why could this happen?